# How to figure out the four digit for American express having all the numbers besides the card or the 4 digit

Tags: encryption

How to figure out the 4 digit code for expiration without having the physical card in hand

Comment: You cannot "figure them out" from the card number. Only by brute forcing, which generally blocks the card quickly.

Answer (score 1):

At least until some time ago, there was no link at all between the card number and the expiration date. I.e. I remember I got a new Amex card with the identical number and just a new expiration date shortly before the old one did expire. It may be different for other card brands and it may have changed.

Nevertheless, if the expiration date could be derived from the card number it would not make any sense at all as an extra security feature.